# Input selection using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am relatively new to powershell .How can i provide a user selection scenario in powershell ?. I am able to write the script by getting the parameters from the user by having them type it instead of just letting them select from the given options . The below is my scenario

```
Env:
  1) staging
  2) prod 
Selection:

Select action to perform:
  1) foo
  2) bar
Selection:

Schedule or leave blank to schedule now (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss):

note (leave blank to skip):

Plan of action:
  >> Sending action to:
  >> Scheduling a action of:
  >> Schedule date: 
  >> Notes:
Ok to proceed? (Y|N):
```

Any help in pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated. Thanks for your time

Comment: With PowerShell the best practice method would be to make a function or script that has parameters for the input. But if you wanted to do the way you showed, you could use `Read-Host` and `Write-Host` cmdlets.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- [PromptForChoice method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice(v=vs.85).aspx) for inputs coming from a list of values
- Read-Host for the free input
- Read-Host combined to [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice(v=vs.85).aspxDateTime.TryParseExact) method for the date input

This way you can handle easily default value for choice from a list, ensure that the date entered is a valid `DateTime` and provide user friendly (because PowerShell standard) help for the requested inputs.

See the snippet below:

```
$envChoice = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]](@(
    (New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription("&Staging", "Staging environment")),
    (New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription("&Prod", "Production environment"))
))
$actionChoice = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]](@(
    (New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription("&Foo", "foo")),
    (New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription("&Bar", "bar"))
))
$environment = $Host.Ui.PromptForChoice("Environment", "Choose the target environment", $envChoice, 0)
$action = $Host.Ui.PromptForChoice("Action", "Select action to perform", $actionChoice, 0)

$dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
$schedule = [String]::Empty
$schedTime = [DateTime]::MinValue
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$provider = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
while (-not [DateTime]::TryParseExact($schedule, $dateFormat, $provider, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref]$schedTime)) {
    Write-Output ("Schedule or leave blank to schedule now ({0}):" -f $dateFormat.ToLower())
    $schedule = Read-Host
    if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($schedule)) {
        $schedule = [DateTime]::Now.ToString($dateFormat)
    }
}

Write-Output "Note (leave blank to skip):"
$note = Read-Host

$confirmChoice = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]](@(
    (New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription("&Yes","Confirm")),
    (New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription("&No","Cancel"))
))
$answer = $Host.Ui.PromptForChoice((@"
Plan of action:
  >> Sending action to: {0}
  >> Scheduling a action of: {1}
  >> Schedule date: {2:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
  >> Notes: {3}
"@ -f $envChoice[$environment].Label.Replace("&",""),$actionChoice[$action].Label.Replace("&",""),$schedTime,$note),"Ok to proceed?",$confirmChoice,0)

Switch ($answer){
    0 {"Should proceed"; break}
    1 {"Cancelled"; break}
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
PS C:\> 45309660.ps1

Environment
Choose the target environment
[S] Staging  [P] Prod  [?] Help (default is "S"): ?
S - Staging environment
P - Production environment
[S] Staging  [P] Prod  [?] Help (default is "S"): P

Action
Select action to perform
[F] Foo  [B] Bar  [?] Help (default is "F"): ?
F - foo
B - bar
[F] Foo  [B] Bar  [?] Help (default is "F"): B
Schedule or leave blank to schedule now (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss):
2017-08-04 17:04:54
Note (leave blank to skip):
This is not a note

Plan of action:
  >> Sending action to: Prod
  >> Scheduling a action of: Bar
  >> Schedule date: 2017-08-04 17:04:54
  >> Notes: This is not a note
Ok to proceed?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [?] Help (default is "Y"): N
Cancelled
PS C:\> 45309660.ps1

Environment
Choose the target environment
[S] Staging  [P] Prod  [?] Help (default is "S"):

Action
Select action to perform
[F] Foo  [B] Bar  [?] Help (default is "F"):
Schedule or leave blank to schedule now (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss):

Note (leave blank to skip):


Plan of action:
  >> Sending action to: Staging
  >> Scheduling a action of: Foo
  >> Schedule date: 2017-08-03 13:08:00
  >> Notes:
Ok to proceed?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
Should proceed
PS C:\>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started.

```
Function Do-Stuff
{
    Param($Environment,$Action,$Schedule,$Note)

    <# logic #>
}
$Splat = @{
    Environment='';
    Action='';
    Schedule='';
    Note='';
}

Write-Host "Env:`r`n`t1) staging`r`n`t2) prod`r`nSelection:"
$Splat.Environment = Read-Host

Write-Host "Select action to perform:`r`n`t1) foo`r`n`t2) bar`r`nSelection:"
$Splat.Action = Read-Host

Write-Host "Schedule or leave blank to schedule now (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss):"
$Splat.Schedule = Read-Host

Write-Host "note (leave blank to skip):"
$Splat.Note = Read-Host

Write-Host @"
Plan of action:
  >> Sending action to: $($Splat.Environment)
  >> Scheduling a action of: $($Splat.Action)
  >> Schedule date: $($Splat.Schedule)
  >> Notes: $($Splat.Note)
Ok to proceed? (Y|N):"@
$Agree = Read-Host
If ($Agree.ToUpper() -eq 'Y')
{
    Do-Stuff @Splat
}
```

Comment: As a best practice, you shouldn't use `Write-Host` unless you're certain you don't need the output.  Otherwise you can use `Write-Output` or `Write` (alias for `Write-Output`) or even just quoting on its own line will accomplish the same thing: string output on the output/success (1) stream.